# Facebook android SDK and App Distribution and Deep Linking

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to make App Distribution from Facebook for android apps. But the official docs don't mention this possibility for android. 
To be clear, the second part of step 9 in Facebook tutorial for iOS:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#linktoapp

is what I need, but
Facebook tutorial for android:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

doesn't mention such a possibility.
Is there a way to implement this kind of app distribution or not?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently you can't do this on Android. But it is on the way, I was recently told 'within weeks' by a Facebook developer at one of their mobile hack days.

UPDATE: 
The sdk for this is now available, here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/

Comment: Thanks Rupert, you have my vote. Would you be so kind to write a post here when they are done?

Comment: yep that would be interesting! Should you update your answer when you get feedback from the facebook  dudes?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone will search for this, now it's possible to use facebook deep linking on Android. Here's their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/#deeplink).